# Architectural options of an elastic computational nodes in Java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, queue, load-balancing, distributed-computing

I have an application that needs to compute `foo(String parm1, String parm2): String`.

Let us assume that the method foo is computationally intensive.

I would like to have a simple processes sitting on say AWS micro instances that computes foo.

Say for simplicity's sake I start 10 micro instances running JVM processes that compute foo.

The question I have is:

I am looking for a framework that will automatically load balance calls from my foo calling processes to my foo compute nodes. And, preferably, allow me to add compute nodes if needed.

Notes:

I can implement this using several architectures (none of which I like -- I'm looking for something more seamless):

1. Use a Queue as a load distribution mechanism -- however then I have to manage going from a tightly coupled call to an asynchronous mechanism and then back -- don't like this too much
2. I could have the callee look up some sort of a name service and randomly pick a compute node and invoke a web service call -- again not too fond of this.
3. AWS has a loadblancer as a commenter pointed out -- however I'm looking for a solution at the architectural level.
4. Someone suggested using haproxy, this is a good approach, one I've considered, however I'd really like an in-JVM solution.
5. One could look at the Haddop MapReduce analogy, I'm looking for something that offers the ability to send a tightly coupled method call to compute nodes in a fashion similar to the way Hadoop sends MapReduce to available compute nodes.

Comment: Doesn't AWS offer built-in load-balancing services?  Have you considered #2 utilizing this service?

Comment: @cheeken, good point, but let's assume I had 10 servers sitting on my rack. The question really pertains to finding a software architectural solution.

Answer (score 2):

For such purposes haproxy load balancer is a very good solution I think. It provides a list of load balance strategies, supports various protocols.

Comment: Interesting, thought I'm looking for an in JVM solution.

Comment: I think clients should know nothing about your cluster. E.g. if the number of your nodes changes  you have to modify the client code.

Comment: good point. So for instance Hadoop has a way of elastically submitting stuff to compute nodes. I guess I'm looking for similar levels of transparency.

Answer (score 2):

The combination of Amazon [elastic load balancer](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/) and [auto scaling](http://aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/) group that is available in AWS should give you a simple and scalable solution.

Auto Scaling is triggered to add instances or remove instances based on metrics that you decide. It can be the number or requests on the ELB, or the load on the instances.

If you have constant load you should consider using larger instances that can process things in parallel with multiple cores. It is better to have a large instance than a few micro instances from price point of view.